# can customize bootstrap certain navbar in this case?

Tags: html, css

Hard to customize bootstrap navigation in this case? I want down navigation to be the same as top navigation in bootstrap.

[image]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul style="padding-top: 15px" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a style="border-right:1px solid black " href="#">Accessories <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a style="border-right:1px solid black " href="#">Promotions</a></li>
            <li><a style="border-right:1px solid black " href="#">PC</a></li>
            <li><a style="border-right:1px solid black " href="#">Playstation</a></li>
            <li><a style="border-right:1px solid black" href="#">Xbox</a></li>
            <li><a style="border-right:1px solid black" href="#">Wii</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form style="margin-top: 0px" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button style="height: 79px;border-radius: 0px" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
  </span>
                    <input style="height: 79px;width: 260px;border-right: none;border-radius: 0;" type="text"
                           class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain further?

Comment: look at this code that i wrote , and my navbar is in bottom of pic,so i want to create top navbar but its hard to me